# Existence of closed ball outside of closed convex set.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $K\subseteq H$ a closed convex subset, with $p\in \partial K$. Is there $B$, a closed ball, with $B \cap K=\emptyset$ and $\text{conv}(B,p)\cap K=\{p\}$?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. It should be clear from looking at the drawing you made. Try moving the point $p$ (in your drawing  ! )along the boundary of $K$ and you will clearly see that for some $p$ the cone $Conv(B,p)$ intersects $K$ at more than one point.

Another counterexample :

Consider $H = \mathbb R^2$,  $K = [0,1]^2$ , $p = (0,0)$ and $B_\epsilon$ the closed ball centered at $(2,2)$ with radius $\epsilon$.

For $\epsilon$ small enough $B_\epsilon \cap K = \varnothing $ but Conv$(B_\epsilon,p) \cap K$ will always contain the diagonal $[(0,0),(1,1)]$ of the square K.

Comment: Can the statement be made true if we also have to find $B$?

Comment: I dont understand your question. Do you mean : Given $p$ on the boundary of a closed set $K$ does there always exist a closed ball $B$ such that Conv $(B,p) \cap K= \{p\}$ ?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question.

Comment: I suspect that this is true in the finite dimensionnal case. If you take $p \in \partial K$ then $p$ is on a face $F$ of $K$. Hence you can find a hyperplane $H$ such that $p \in F = H \cap K$.  Then take $B$ in the halfspace defined by $H$ which does not contain $K$ and it should workout.